# Firefox not respecting max-width/height in parent without set width/height

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, parent-child

I've got a strange problem, in Chrome/Safari, the image respects it's max width/height styling inside of a parent with no set width/height. but not in Firefox/Opera.

```
<div id="container">
    <figure>
        <img src="http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/dslr/d90/img/sample/pic_001b.jpg">
    </figure>
</div>
```

That's the image and it's containers. The CSS is as follows:

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#container {
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    margin: auto;
}
figure {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
    line-height: 0;
}
img {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

The `figure` element is only there to serve as an overlay to the image by using the `:before` selector, but that doesn't work if it has a set width/height. Is there any way to get Firefox and Opera to respect the grandparents height/width instead?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GUrkj/1/

Answer (score 0):

See [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-height)

Specifically:

> The max-height CSS property is used to set the maximum height of a
> given element. It prevents the used value of the height property from
> becoming larger than the value specified for max-height.

And...

> The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the
> generated box's containing block. If the height of the containing
> block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content
> height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the percentage
> value is treated as none.

What the last part means, is that in Firefox at least, without a `height` value explicitly stated, `max-height` becomes `none` - resulting in the observerd behaviour.

As such you will need to add  `height` and `width` to the `figure` element at the least.

Comment: I'm relying on the figure element to not have fixed height/width for the overlay to wrap around the image nicely, are you sure there's no other way?

Answer (score 0):

In CSS when you use 100% you are always saying "100%" of my parent. If your parent is unconstrained so are you. The trick here is that the height is the only one that matters, set the figure height to 100%, but don't set its width and you should be fine.